# Adding property using Object assign

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following function:

```
addHrefs = (list) => {
    const listWithHrefs = list.map((item) => {
        item.href = customFunction(item.name);
        return item;
    });
    return listWithHrefs;
}
```

The problem here is I am mutating the `list` object. I want to know how to add a particular `(key, value)` pair without mutating `list`. Is it possible with `Object.assign`? How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

> The **`Object.assign()`** method is used to copy the values of all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

You could assign the property value to a new object and return it.

```
addHrefs = list =>
    list.map(item => Object.assign({}, item, { href: customFunction(item.name) }));
```

Comment: Notice that this might not mutate `list`, but still uses mutation.

Comment: @Nina Scholz It worked. But I can not understand why `list` was mutated (so I supposed I had to work with `Object.assign`). I tried in a javascript console the `map` function and it did not mutate my list object `b = a.map(function(i){return i * 2})` and then `JSON.stringify(a) === JSON.stringify(b)` was false, so I guess is a ES6 behaviour, if it is, can you explain me why `list` was mutated?

Comment: it mutates `list`, because `item` gets mutated, because `item` is a reference to an object. your example does not change any object.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass plain object as first parameter to `Object.assign()`, referenced object at second parameter. Perform action on variable assigned to `Object.assign()`, return variable

```js
let list = [{
  a: 1
}, {
  a: 2
}, {
  a: 3
}];

let res = list.map(item => {
  let o = Object.assign({}, item);
  // do stuff with `o`
  o.a = o.a + 10;
  // return `o`
  return o
});

console.log(list, res);
```